# Cut and Copy do not always work

Tags: clipboard

There seems to be something interfering with the cut/copy process. Approximately every other time I try to copy/cut (using ctrl + c/x or menu), nothing ends up in the clipboard. I noticed this issue in a variety of programs (Firefox, Thunderbird, Libreoffice).
How do I start troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: Do you have a virtual machine running when you have this problem?

Comment: No. I don't have any virtual machine installed.

Comment: I confirm this happens now and then.

Comment: Might be related to this bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/878

Comment: It seems we'll have to wait for gtk3 3.24.13 and mutter 3.34.2 to be released and updated upstream.